# Import rpy gives error

Tags: python, r

I have tried installing rpy using the download on `http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpy/files/latest/download?source=directory`

I get this error:

```
from rpy import *
Unable to determine R version from the registry. Trying another method.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from rpy import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy.py", line 53, in <module>
    RHOME = rpy_tools.get_R_HOME()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy_tools.py", line 57, in get_R_HOME
    raise RuntimeError("Couldn't execute the R interpreter.\n"
RuntimeError: Couldn't execute the R interpreter.
Check whether R is in the execution path.
```

Why is this hapenning and how can i stop it?

Comment: do you have R installed?

Comment: yes i installed it today

Comment: if you open your cmd.exe can you type R and have it go into R? you probably just need to add it to your path ..

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of `R` installed? And is your `rpy` version matches `R` version?

Answer (score 0):

During the installation of R a checkbox is shown giving you the option to add the R version number to your registry.

Maybe you did not check it? Reinstalling R might help.

[image]